# How to intercept wp_mail function and add an attachment to it

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin where i need to intercept wp_mail function "executed from another plugin" and add an attachment file to its headers, point me in the right direction where i can intercept this call from my custom plugin.

the code that executes the wp_mail function

```
    $message = apply_filters( 'frm_email_message', $message, $atts );
    $header         = apply_filters('frm_email_header', $header, array(
        'to_email' => $atts['to_email'], 'subject' => $atts['subject'],
    ) );        

    $sent = wp_mail($recipient, $atts['subject'], $message, $header, $atts['attachments']);
    if ( ! $sent ) {
        $header = 'From: '. $atts['from'] ."\r\n";
        $recipient = implode(',', (array) $recipient);
        $sent = mail($recipient, $atts['subject'], $message, $header);
    }
```

I think i found the solution in case some one else was looking for this too.
from the wordpress codex here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'my_wp_mail_filter' );
function my_wp_mail_filter( $args ) {

    $new_wp_mail = array(
        'to'          => $args['to'],
        'subject'     => $args['subject'],
        'message'     => $args['message'],
        'headers'     => $args['headers'],
        'attachments' => $args['attachments'],
    );

    return $new_wp_mail;
}
```

the above solution seems to be not working.

Comment: You should consider adding a filter to `frm_email_message` instead of `wp_mail`

Comment: @mevius Thank you that is actually what i was looking for a step ahead of wp_mail is much better

Comment: @mevius it seems none of the above solutions working as expected the wp_mail is fired without add_fitler